# Multiple events on markers of Android Map V2

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, android-maps-v2

thanks to the method SetOnInfoWindowClickListener, i put a Listener on my GoogleMap, then I want to manage with " On Info Window Click " the opening of a new activity diffent for each marker of my Google Map. My problem is that the method can manage only 1 marker for all my GoogleMap instead of manage different Marker.

There the code :

```
public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
           Intent intent = new Intent(MapActivity.this,OtherActivity.class);
           startActivity(intent);
```

}

Anyone have an answer for this issue ?

Thanks.

Comment: do you have different titles for marker?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16885401/android-google-maps-v2-oninfowindowclick-on-several-markers This was asked 20 minutes earlier than your question.