# how can open a specific layout clicking a infowindow ? - googlemap api 2

Tags: javascript, android, eclipse, google-maps, infowindow

Simple, when i click the entire infowindow on marker, i want he open a specific layout

and if i have 10 marker with different infowindow each one, how can i get when i click them, a different layout for each one ?

This is my Code on one of my maps:

```
import java.util.HashMap;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class Fragment17 extends SherlockFragment {

//create hashmap
private HashMap<Marker, Integer> hash = new HashMap<Marker, Integer>();


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment17, container, false);
    return rootView;
}

//
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View v, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onViewCreated(v, savedInstanceState);

final LatLng Initial = new LatLng(-34.673009, -58.474111);

final LatLng FADU = new LatLng(-34.542163, -58.443716);

final LatLng UNO = new LatLng(-34.524924, -58.576421);
final LatLng DOS = new LatLng(-34.755415, -58.577794);


GoogleMap googlemap;

        googlemap  = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map17)).getMap();

        googlemap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        googlemap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(Initial, 10);
        googlemap.animateCamera(update);

        //modify
        Marker marker1 = googlemap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(FADU).title("FADU").snippet("Facultad de Arquitectura, Diseño y Urbanismo")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE)));
        hash.put(marker1, R.drawable.logo);

        Marker marker2 = googlemap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(UNO).title("TEOREMA").snippet("san matin 1245"));
        hash.put(marker2, R.drawable.teorema);

        Marker marker3 = googlemap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(DOS).title("El Mundo del Acrilico").snippet("san benito 2144"));
        hash.put(marker3, R.drawable.mundoacrilico);

        googlemap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });



        googlemap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new InfoWindowAdapter() {

             @Override
             public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {

             View v = getLayoutInflater(null).inflate(R.layout.infowindow, null);

             TextView titulo = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.titulo);
             TextView direccion = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.direccion);
             ImageView imagen = ((ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.imagen));

             titulo.setText(marker.getTitle());
             direccion.setText(marker.getSnippet());

             if(hash.get(marker) != null)
                imagen.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(hash.get(marker)));

             return v;

            }
                //..
             @Override
                public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return null;
                }
             });
            }
//...
```

---

**EDIT**

sorry i try to explain better.

This is my app, when i click the marker appear the infowindow corresponding:

[image]

So when i click the infowindow i would like that call a new layout,

[image]

I understand what you're saying, but I know when to apply when you have that many different infowindow should call different classes.

also have a hashmap to organize the content of infowindow and not know if that complicates me or not the method **setOnInfoWindowClickListener**

---

**EDIT**

**I resolved my problem whit [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16885401/android-google-maps-v2-oninfowindowclick-on-several-markers/24113881#24113881) post**

**thanks.**

Comment: once you click the infowindow open a specific class, that is what i want, but my problem is i have 20 diferent infowindow and y i want each one open a different class

Comment: I resolved my problem whit this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16885401/android-google-maps-v2-oninfowindowclick-on-several-markers/24113881#24113881 thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure what you are asking but you implemented the **setOnInfoWindowClickListener** so you get the marker that was selected as an argument to the **onInfoWindowClick** method.  Once you have the marker that was selected you can start a new activity with the layout you want to use.