# How to get click event at info when marker clicked?

Tags: android, code-snippets, marker

I want to show new activity when user touch the info(snippet?) above marker. As I'm new comer for android, I studied alone and completed by custom marker and snippet. But I can not give a click event to snippet. I already checked for [How to get click event of the marker text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17549372/how-to-get-click-event-of-the-marker-text) this post but it is hard to perform on my code. At the start "InfoWindowAdapter" it couldn't read it(can not resolve...)

I found second answer [Android Google Maps V2 - OnInfoWindowClick on several markers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16885401/android-google-maps-v2-oninfowindowclick-on-several-markers) it looks find except one part.

```
allMarkerMap.put(mk1, Don.class);
mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(this);
```

Above post, it said that it works but at my one it has red line on "this" next to `mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener`. I put it on several position such as under `onCreate`, `onMapready` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you look closely at the code provided in [your link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16885401/android-google-maps-v2-oninfowindowclick-on-several-markers) you will notice the following line:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnInfoWindowClickListener {
```

Which means the Activity implements the `OnInfoWindowClickListener` interface. If you want to use `mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(this);` make sure `this` (which in the provided link is the Activity) implements the listener.

By implementing the `OnInfoWindowClickListener` it will force you to implement the `onInfoWindowClick(marker)` method.

Comment: Thank you! I need to step by step from the basic....... ha...... anyway it works! Thank you Kilian!